# Best choice for Long-polling / Comet in Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java, comet, long-polling

Which native server is best, in your opinion, to implement long-polling / [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))? The first target application is chat, but there will be other implementations - we basically need push-to-client capabilities.

I'm limiting the answers to C# or Java because these two technologies are dominant at my workplace. The requirements are as usual: performance, ease of deployment/programming, customization, ...

Answer (score 2):

IIS + [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync) is a very straight-forward, scalable and extensible solution for server push.  There is a free Community edition I highly recommend checking out.

Answer (score 2):

Both Java and .NET platforms have enough capabilities to handle your needs. If you choose Java : You may start with [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org) otherwise, on the .net side [PokeIn](http://pokein.com) library should be the choice.

Comment: DWR with Apache for JAVA | 
PokeIn with IIS/Apache/Ngix for .NET would be best

Answer (score 2):

I just saw this blogpost from Scott Hanselman yesterday. It looks very promising.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

It features an opensource product called SignalR which is available through nuget.

You can find an example chat application in the sources @ github

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: SignalR would be the best choice if .NET. Also in the ASP.net webstack

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a significant difference in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Try [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) project. It's a Java framework with long-pooling and websocket support using famous [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I know that special attention was paid to Comet support in the Grizzly engine used by Glassfish. It wasn't treated as an afterthought.

Comment: That's interesting.  What sort of special support does it have?